# Laravel - test. How to fix the Error Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, tdd

I can't run this test method, what I want to do is that only the administrator user can enter the panel, if the user is only a user, it must receive the status 302 but it receives 404,

If I run php artisan route:list I can see the route

Here is my test method:

```
/** @test */
   public function usuario_no_administrador_no_puede_entrar_al_panel()
   {

           $role = factory(Role::class)->create(['name' => 'usuario']);
           $user = factory(User::class)->create();
           $user->roles()->sync($role);

           $this->actingAs($user);

           $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
           $this->get('/panel')->assertStatus(302);

   }
```

Here is my web.php file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:usuario', 'middleware' => 'role:administrador'], function() {
  Route::get('/panel', 'PanelController@index')->name('panel.index');
});
```

And here is the error:

[Image of error when running php artisan test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSCPT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `middleware` keys in your route group definition. You’ll need to combine them, as otherwise the last one will override any previously-set ones:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:usuario', 'role:administrador']], function() {
    Route::get('/panel', 'PanelController@index')->name('panel.index');
});
```